# How to sort student result based on subjects

Tags: mysql, php

I have this mysql table

[image: Database Table]

How can i sort this MYSQL table to this output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can get the data needed by using a query like that:

```
SELECT subject_name, category, sum(student_mark)
FROM table_name
GROUP BY subject_name, category
```

To apply the % ratios you can use an extra table:

```
SELECT t.subject_name, t.category, sum(t.student_mark) * r.ratio
FROM table_name t
JOIN 
(
SELECT 'Assignment' AS category, 10 AS ratio
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Test' AS category, 20 AS ratio
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Examination' AS category, 70 AS ratio
) r ON t.category = r.category
GROUP BY subject_name, category
```

This way you should get the data you need and then you can try to pivot the table to present it like you want.

I didn't test the queries so let me know if it doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, please i'm new to php, how do output it differently as assignment, test, and exams scores respectively, because am using table for the output.